# What tree distance libraries in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, tree

I'm looking for a library that implements any of the seemingly well documented* strategies for calculating the distance between trees.

For example, the library should show that these two trees

```
  a              a
 / \            / \
b   c          b   c
                    \
                     d
```

are more 'similar' than these two

```
  a              x
 / \            / \
b   c          y   z
```

I'm using node.js so a node implementation would be nice. I'm aware that 'similar' seems somewhat ambiguous, but no matter what strategy you would use to compute the difference between these trees, I'm assuming you would always end up with some final 'score' that, if representing an edit distance, would be larger in the second case than in the first.

What node.js libraries do anything like this?

EDIT: Some added info on my specific case: This is for detecting repeating tree structures in html documents, so libraries more specialized to that problem would be even better.

EDIT2: Even a levenshtein distance library for node.js would help so I could at least do comparisons on fingerprint text of the tree.

*I'm new to the field, but [scribd.com](http://www.scribd.com/doc/49451396/pattern-matching-algorithms-9780195113679-37394?in_collection=3724457) discusses strategies used by Lu and Tai.

Comment: A simple levenshtein library for node.js: https://gist.github.com/982927

Comment: There is no "liechtenstein distance". How are these trees formatted, do you have already parsed the XML? Or does it need to work on HTML strings? Which aspects of a DOM tree would you like to compare?

Comment: thanks @Bergi, typo corrected. Only comparing tag name. Currently I have a DOM creating by parsing HTML with cheerio, but all those parts are trivial AFAIK.

Comment: If your nodes are short strings (or convertible to them), you could do an in order traversal of your tree and then use a string distance algorithm. Here's a levenshtein distance implementation for node: [Levenshtein Distance in Javascript (Node.js)](http://www.andreimackenzie.com/Levenshtein_Distance_in_JavaScript_%28Node.js%29/)